# Problem with component loading after angular update

Tags: angular, webpack

I am currently updating angular app from 2.0 version to 7.23.
I am actually after 3 days of facing milion of errors, problems and configurations. Now I have got to the place where webpack build my project but my components don't load properly.
I get zone.js?d135:3243 GET http://localhost:8080/component-name 404 (Not Found)
for every component in my app. I guess its something wrong with my configuration so it is:

Problem solved!:

Added angular-template-loader && angular-router-loader to my webpack configuration.

Comment: Based on the error it looks like it's an error with your routing, can you post your router?

Comment: And the app.module.ts?

Comment: Nothing really jumps out at me, but I'm not sure why you're using `ModuleWithProviders` as the type for the router module. In my app, I have an actual angular module `AppRouterModule` that sets up the routes and exports it. Have you tried doing something like that?

Comment: I have already tried AppRouterModule but the error is still the same.

Comment: I see. Sorry I can't be of more help. I'd probably have to debug this to figure it out.

Comment: I will try by myself. Thank you anyway for taking a look.